# How to plot a system of coupled PDEs using NDSolve

Tags: plotting, differential-equations, visualization

I am trying to solve the the following system of couples PDEs using NDSolve. However I am struggling to plot the solutions. I am trying to plot |u1[t,x]|^2 (i.e. the square of the absolute value) but whenever I try I get a blank 3D box as opposed to any actual results. How could I get the results to show in 3D? I have attached the code below.

I have tried the following line:

Plot3D[u1[t, x] /. sol, {t, 0, 5}, {x, -a, a}] but it generates an blank box.

```
eq = {

I*D[u1[t, x], {t, 1}] + D[u1[t, x], {x, 2}] + u6[t,x]+u2[t,x]  == 0, 
I*D[u2[t, x], {t, 1}] + D[u2[t, x], {x, 2}] + u1[t,x]+u3[t,x]  == 0,
I*D[u3[t, x], {t, 1}] + D[u3[t, x], {x, 2}] + u2[t,x]+u4[t,x]  == 0,
I*D[u4[t, x], {t, 1}] + D[u4[t, x], {x, 2}] + u3[t,x]+u5[t,x]  == 0,
I*D[u5[t, x], {t, 1}] + D[u5[t, x], {x, 2}] + u4[t,x]+u6[t,x]  == 0,
I*D[u6[t, x], {t, 1}] + D[u6[t, x], {x, 2}] + u5[t,x]+u1[t,x]  == 0,

u1[0, x] == f1,
u2[0, x] == f2,
u3[0, x] == f3,
u4[0, x] == f4,
u5[0, x] == f5,
u6[0, x] == f6,

u1[t, -a] == u1[t, a],
u2[t, -a] == u2[t, a],
u3[t, -a] == u3[t, a],
u4[t, -a] == u4[t, a],
u5[t, -a] == u5[t, a],
u6[t, -a] == u6[t, a]

};

sol = NDSolve[eq,{u1[t,x],u2[t,x],u3[t,x],u4[t,x],u5[t,x],u6[t,x]}, {t, 0, 5}, {x, -a, a}, MaxStepSize -> 0.07];
```

Comment: This is not the complete code. What values did you use for `a, f1, f2, f3, f4, f5, f6`?

Comment: a has value 10 and f1 = 0, f2 = 0,f3 = 0, f4 = 0, f5 = 0, f6 = 0 for example, I am just trying to display something as opposed to getting a blank box.

Comment: Edit your question to include the values given in your comment. `Plot3D` has the attribute `HoldAll`. Use `Evaluate`, i.e., `Plot3D[Evaluate[u1[t, x] /. sol], {t, 0, 5}, {x, -a, a}]`

Answer (score 3):

We can't get something from zero initial data and periodic boundary condition. If we put some initial data, for instance for `u1`, then we have (see attentively how we use `sol` and `Abs` for complex solution):

```
eq = {I*D[u1[t, x], {t, 1}] + D[u1[t, x], {x, 2}] + u6[t, x] + 
     u2[t, x] == 0, 
   I*D[u2[t, x], {t, 1}] + D[u2[t, x], {x, 2}] + u1[t, x] + 
     u3[t, x] == 0, 
   I*D[u3[t, x], {t, 1}] + D[u3[t, x], {x, 2}] + u2[t, x] + 
     u4[t, x] == 0, 
   I*D[u4[t, x], {t, 1}] + D[u4[t, x], {x, 2}] + u3[t, x] + 
     u5[t, x] == 0, 
   I*D[u5[t, x], {t, 1}] + D[u5[t, x], {x, 2}] + u4[t, x] + 
     u6[t, x] == 0, 
   I*D[u6[t, x], {t, 1}] + D[u6[t, x], {x, 2}] + u5[t, x] + 
     u1[t, x] == 0, u1[0, x] == Sin[2 Pi x/a], u2[0, x] == f2, 
   u3[0, x] == f3, u4[0, x] == f4, u5[0, x] == f5, u6[0, x] == f6, 
   u1[t, -a] == u1[t, a], u2[t, -a] == u2[t, a], 
   u3[t, -a] == u3[t, a], u4[t, -a] == u4[t, a], 
   u5[t, -a] == u5[t, a], u6[t, -a] == u6[t, a]};
par = {a = 10, f1 = 1, f2 = 0, f3 = 0, f4 = 0, f5 = 0, 
  f6 = 0}; var = {u1, u2, u3, u4, u5, u6};
sol = NDSolve[eq, var, {t, 0, 5}, {x, -a, a}, 
  Method -> {"MethodOfLines", 
    "SpatialDiscretization" -> {"TensorProductGrid", 
      "MinPoints" -> 100, "MaxPoints" -> 100, 
      "DifferenceOrder" -> "Pseudospectral"}}]


Table[Plot3D[
  Evaluate[Abs[var[[i]][t, x]] /. First[sol]], {t, 0, 5}, {x, -a, a}, 
  Mesh -> None, ColorFunction -> "Rainbow", AxesLabel -> Automatic, 
  PlotLabel -> var[[i]]], {i, Length[var]}]
```

[image: Figure 1]